# How can I get SoapClient to respect a session?

Tags: php, session, soap, soap-client

I am working with a SOAP API for an e-commerce shopping cart and I can't seem to be able to get the session to persist through different pages.

As an example, I have some test code below (with a bunch of debug messages) which adds an item to the cart and then views the cart.  When I run this in my browser it works perfectly, but if I refresh the page, I am expecting there to then be two items in the cart (one from each of the two page calls).  However, it doesn't seem to remember anything from previous calls to the page.  I know the API is working because if I just call "AddToCart" twice on this page and then call "GetCartContents" I see the 2 items in the cart correctly.

Am I missing something?

```
<?php 
session_start();

$url = "https://www.example.com/soap-checkout.php?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0));

if (!empty($_SESSION['soapcookies'])) {
    foreach($_SESSION['soapcookies'] AS $name=>$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            foreach($value AS $k=>$v) {
                $client->__setCookie($name[$k], $v);
            }
        } else {
            $client->__setCookie($name, $value);
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre style='background: grey;'>browser cookies: ".print_r($_COOKIE, true)."</pre>";//debug

// Add to Cart
$data = array( 
    "domain" => 'www.example.net', 
    "sku"    => "1234",
    "qty"    => 1
);
$result = $client->__soapCall("AddToCart", $data);
$responseHeader = $client->__getLastResponseHeaders();//debug
echo "<pre style='background: purple;'>responseHeader: ".print_r($responseHeader, true)."</pre>";//debug
echo "<pre style='background: grey;'>cookies: ".print_r($client->_cookies, true)."</pre>";//debug
echo "<pre style='background: yellow;'>Result of 'AddToCart': ".print_r($result, true)."</pre>";//debug

// Set SOAP Cookies in PHP Session
$_SESSION['soapcookies'] = $client->_cookies;

// View Cart
$data = array(
    "domain" => 'www.example.net'
);
$result = $client->__soapCall("GetCartContents", $data);
echo "<pre style='background: skyblue;'>Result of 'GetCartContents': ".print_r($result, true)."</pre>";//debug
?>
```

FYI, the PHP version is 5.2.6

Comment: Are you saying the session in PHP isn't working, or the passing sessions to SOPA isn't working? Might help if you debug if the session data is being passed in.

Comment: @Robbie The PHP session is working just fine.  I guess my main question is what do I need to do to maintain the same session.  **(1)** I was attempting to read the cookies that SOAP creates, **(2)** save it into a PHP session and then **(3)** if there is an existing soap cookie in the session, to set the cookie in SOAP to be the same as it was before.  Not sure if that's the right method, so I'd appreciate alternatives.  However, if it is the way to go, how do I set the cookie? When I get the cookie, I get an array, but setCookie is requiring a string for each cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks correct, if your goal is to attempt to tie an active user session to particular interactions with the SOAP API. Your approach to store and set the SOAP cookies in the session and restoring to SOAP session via setCookie is also the way to go.

Your code is not working probably due to the error on the line:

```
$client->__setCookie($name[$k], $v);
```

Which needs to be:

```
$client->__setCookie($name, $v);
```

Hope that helps.